# Macro or any automation for generating variables from text in the project files for converting project in multi language?

Tags: codeigniter, automation, macros, phpstorm, multilingual

I was almost done with my project when suddenly requirements got changed and I need to support multilanguage in CMS. 
If I will do it manually I am going to need almost 3 to 4 days for replacing the text with new variables and saving them in a database.

I am developing this project using CodeIgniter and PhpStorm as editor. Can anybody please help me with this situation?

Is there any automation or how can I develop any automation tool which fetches the labels and put them in a database with any random non-existing key and replace that key with a label in the file. Can it be done through regular expression?